# what's the syntax for telling VI to read/write a source file with soft-tabs and a specified indentation?

Tags: emacs, vim, vi

Someplace I saw a snippet of code which told vi to use soft tabs and set the size of a tab. If you put this snippet at the bottom of a source file, then vi would magically use those settings for that file.

What is the syntax and rules for including that snippet in a source file?  Can emacs be made to use these settings as well?

Comment: Some experimentation based on the answers below shows there's a bit more to it than just adding the lines.  One issue is that you need `:set modeline modelines=5` to make Vim scan up to 5 lines for the modeline notation.  Another issue is that even with those set, `vim` won't necessarily accept the modeline controls when editing a C file, even if the exact same modeline works fine when editing an 'untyped' file (I used `junk` as the untyped file and `qs07int.c` for the C file).  I'm not sure what is overriding the modeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put this in a comment in your source file:

```
ex: set softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 expandtab:
```

The comment syntax depends on the type of the source file.

For C/C++/Java, this would be:

```
// ex: set softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 expandtab:
```

For JSP, this would be:

```
<%-- ex: set softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 expandtab: --%>
```

This works if it is placed at the beginning of the source file, but I'm not sure that this'll work if placed at the end of it too.

This will not work for emacs. There might be a different way of achieving the same for emacs.

Comment: `ex` is a less common (though perfectly valid) modeline prefix. Much more common is `vim`; `vi` also works. Note that there *must* be a blank character before it, so the first example here would not actually work, but the second two do. (And vim itself doesn't care about the comment syntax, of course.)

Answer (score 3):

Check out `:h modeline`.

Example:

```
/* vim: ai set sw=4 ts=4 */
```

See `:h modelines` for how many lines into a file Vim will check for modeline info.  The default is to check the first 5 lines.

Comment: 'modelines' is the number of lines to check at the beginning AND end of the file.

Comment: You missed my favorite 'et'.  Let the indentation wars begin!

Comment: Is it more conventional to place the `set` at the start of the list of options?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, vi didn't have this capability.  You're likely thinking of the [modeline feature](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_21.html#21.6) of Vim.  There is similar functionality in emacs, where you can put [local variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html#File-Variables) in the file.

Note that, at least in Vim, modelines have had a history of vulnerabilities.  This is primarily due to problematic options being specifically blacklisted instead of only allowing a certain subset of variables to be set in modelines.  I'd suggest using a plugin like [securemodelines](http://github.com/ciaranm/securemodelines).

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your C++ source file:

```
// vim: set ft=cpp
```

The [modeline feature](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic) looks for the string "`vim:`" and then executes what follows.  Note: this could open up potential exploits if you don't trust the files you are opening, so think twice before enabling this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all, in *real* vi you do this in the .exrc file.

Second, use

```
set autoindent tabstop=8 shiftwidth=4
```

because otherwise vi will insert tabs it thinks are only 4 characters wide.  The resulting text file will not look like it makes sense in any other editor.