# how to specify indentation for a file?

Tags: vim

I heard that we can specify VIM indent for a file by embedding the indentation commands into the file to be edited.

Can somebody let me know how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what's the syntax for telling VI to read/write a source file with soft-tabs and a specified indentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662799/whats-the-syntax-for-telling-vi-to-read-write-a-source-file-with-soft-tabs-and-a)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is called a **modeline**.

Here is a modeline that I commonly use [for vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic):

```
/* vim:set softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 expandtab: */
```

A similar thing [for emacs](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/emacs_486.html) would look like this:

```
/* -*- Mode: tab-width: 4; c-basic-offset: 4; indent-tabs-mode: nil -*- */
```

This question has been [covered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662799/whats-the-syntax-for-telling-vi-to-read-write-a-source-file-with-soft-tabs-and-a) though.

Comment: If you notice that a question's been covered before, just post a comment on it so we can close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
// vim: set ts=4 sw=4 et:
```

where `//` is your language's comment marker.

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify indentation for a given filetype.

For example for python files, you can add this line to your .vimrc file:

```
autocmd FileType python set sw=4 sta
```

The advantage compared to modelines is that you don't have to write it everytime. Then for a specific python file, if you want to change the indentation, you can write this modeline:

```
# vim: set sw=2:
```